# Open Windows Visual Basic Express for Windows 8 project using VBE for Web using Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vbe

I am going to work on a project and my colleague is using Microsoft Visual Studio for Windows 8. Since I have windows 7, and because we are creating an app that should also work for browsers, I installed Visual Basic Express 2012 for the Web.

Unfortunately I cannot open his project with my version of Microsoft VBE. I might run a Windows 8 virtual machine, but I hope there is another solution, such that I can open the project and can contribute with my version of VBE.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't work on Windows 8 projects in any Visual Studio that isn't running on Windows 8.